# .NET 6 Mobile App without Cross Platform UI

Tags: .net-6.0, maui

Is it possible to write a mobile app using .NET 6 but still maintain platform specific implementation of UI

So this would involve still using UIViewControllers for iOS and Activities for Android without taking the MAUI approach of writing the UI in a cross platform manner.

If this is possible could you point us at some documentation around how this is achieved.

Comment: Been playing around with MAUI for months now, So as far as I know this is not available in MAUI as of now, I am not even sure if it could be an enhancement that would be added in the future(I hope they do add it tbh). But as of now if you really wanna go ahead with this approach with C#,  Using Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS is your best bet.

Comment: Also if you are worried about Xamarin being a dying platform and MAUI coming as a replacement you might wanna read this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/the-new-net-multi-platform-app-ui-maui/#net-6-and-mobile-sdks

Comment: Really it's a matter of a migration path. We may decide we want to switch to MAUI but we're looking into whether or not it's an option to essentially migrate our existing Xamarin code to .NET 6 first and then look at MAUI.

Comment: What you want is ".Net 6 for iOS" and ".Net 6 for Android". Oddly, there don't seem to be docs for those yet. The .Net 6 code is all there for those platforms, AFAIK. The hard part (because not documented) is getting the desired "multi-targetting" project set up, without the Maui cross-platform UI app startup logic. I recommend not attempting this, until someone knowledgeable creates a good ".net 6 cross-platform mobile multi-targetting" example.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Well That's not ready yet that's why you don't have documentation on it..

Comment: Are you sure? Do you know what **exactly** "is not ready yet"? In VS 2022 Preview: **".Net 6 multi-targetting"** is used by Maui project.  *".Net 6 for iOS"* works - see project template **"iOS Application"**. Likewise for Android. The only thing I don't see, is anyone putting the existing iOS and Android startup logic into a project organized like the Maui project. So that you could easily share c# code that isn't platform-specific. I've been assuming someone knowledgeable enough could do so manually, writing some startup code to direct to the correct platform.

Comment: You can get help from the following posts.                                                                       https://www.andreasnesheim.no/converting-xamarin-ios-template-to-net-6/  and                     https://www.andreasnesheim.no/converting-xamarin-android-template-to-net-6/

Comment: Thanks @Paramjit that looks like the kind of information I was trying to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried to follow the instructions yet but the links provided by @Paramjit in the comments to my original question seem to provide the answer I was looking for, namely that MAUI isn' the only mobile option in .NET 6:

https://www.andreasnesheim.no/converting-xamarin-android-template-to-net-6/
https://www.andreasnesheim.no/converting-xamarin-ios-template-to-net-6/